# Single word for object that is addictive

Tags: single-word-requests, derivation

I am looking for a single word that can be said in replacement of the activity, substance, etc. that an addict is addicted to. eg: In the case that someone is addicted to smoking cigarettes, what would the official title given to the cigarette be?

> An **addict** (person) is **addicted**  to a **_____** (object).

Comment: The addiction??? A sample sentence is really needed to know if any answers are going to work.

Comment: Ryley, what did your search engine, thesaurus and dictionary show when you did the basic research, please?

Comment: An addict is addicted to a reward.

Answer (score 3):

One may get addicted to any of various ***[addictives](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/addictive#English)***:

> noun
>   **addictive** (plural **addictives**)
>    . A drug that causes an addiction.
>    . Anything that is very habit-forming.
>   [wiktionary]

Comment: This isn't in the more authoritative dictionaries I've checked yet, but it's almost guaranteed to be standard in the near future. Compare the nouning of sedative, laxative....

Answer (score 2):

*[Vice](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vice)*
As in "John's vice is cigarettes"
It does have a much wider usage though - can be used to refer to an action, habit or attribute that is considered a weakness.

Answer (score 0):

It can be called the *addictive substance*, or simply *drug*. Sometimes people use *drug* or *fix* to describe their sugar addiction.

Comment: Drug is the best word so far. Look it up in the dictionary, it's not even a metaphor because "something addictive" is given as a definition.

Comment: The question asks about "activity, substance, etc." - a workaholic or chocoholic is not addicted to a drug. Some people are addicted to exercising, or TV, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Vice - I wouldn't use drug because you can be addicted to more things that just drugs. Everyone has a vice though, something they use to help as a coping mechanism. A vice could be anything; food, weed, actual drugs, alcohol, cigarettes, coffee or caffeine, sex, sleep, fighting, etc.

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U. This would benefit from a citation, as it fits, but the same answer is already given.  You can improve your answer with a citation or try another.  Please do take a moment to [tour] the site and read the [FAQ].

Comment: Some people are addicted to exercise - would you call that a vice?

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a stretch but I think it could work:

**pacificer**

> device used for an infant to suck or bite on *(WordNet)*

(I believe this is called a dummy in the UK, a binky or soother in Canada.)

You can also call it "your poison," as in

> Pick your poison (inviting someone to choose an alcoholic beverage).